# How to get only text and image from a div and ignore other html tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get the text and image tags from a div but need to ignore all the other HTML tags. So I wrote a regex to grab data from `>` `<`these tags. But it also removes the image tags also from my div ihtml. How do I resolve this issue?

I have tried so far,

HTML :

```
<div id="div-parent">

<p>
hello world <img src="" alt="image"/>
here we go
</p>
<ul>
  <li>test 1 <img src="" alt="image1"/> list 1</li>
  <li>test 2 <img src="" alt="image2"/> list 2</li>
  <li>test 3 <img src="" alt="image3"/> list 3</li>
  <li>test 4 <img src="" alt="image4"/> list 4</li>
  <li>test 5 <img src="" alt="image5"/> list 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var div = document.getElementById('div-parent')
console.log($(div).html().match(/(^[^<]+<)|(>([^<]+)<)|(>[^<]+$)/g))
//write a loop which iterates the text with image
});
```

I got the output something like this:[image]

Did I miss something? Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
/[^<^>.]*<img [^<^>.]*\/>[^<^>.]*/g
```

Comment: sorry,the editor remove some char like asterisk,I have changed it right, and test it.

Comment: getting null while using this regex :|

Comment: ``` test js
var str='<div id="div-parent">hello world <img src="" alt="image"/>here we go</div>';
str.match(/[^<^>.]*<img [^<^>.]*\/>[^<^>.]*/g);
```

Comment: No errors but. still am getting the li tags. how can I remove that? could u help me out to find a solution? I just need the plain text and images. need to avoid all the other HTML tags  from that div

Comment: ``` js
var str='<div id="div-parent">\
<p>\
hello world <img src="" alt="image"/>\
here we go\
</p>\
<ul>\
  <li>test 1 <img src="" alt="image1"/> list 1</li>\
</ul>\
</div>';
str.match(/[^<^>.]*<img [^<^>.]*\/>[^<^>.]*/g);
```
I run this code,it get the following array,it doesn't have li tags.
0: "hello world <img src=\"\" alt=\"image\"/>here we go"
1: "test 1 <img src=\"\" alt=\"image1\"/> list 1"

Comment: but I want to remove all the other tags from my string

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div-parent">

<p>
hello world <img src="" alt="image"/>
here we go
</p>
<ul>
  <li>test 1 <img src="" alt="image1"/> list 1</li>
  <li>test 2 <img src="" alt="image2"/> list 2</li>
  <li>test 3 <img src="" alt="image3"/> list 3</li>
  <li>test 4 <img src="" alt="image4"/> list 4</li>
  <li>test 5 <img src="" alt="image5"/> list 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var div = document.getElementById('div-parent')
var el = $("#div-parent").find('p,li');
for (var i =0 ; i<el.length; i++) {
console.log(el[i].innerHTML);
}
console.log(el.length)
});

</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @kavitha, I'm afraid I won't get the elements in li by using this loop. can u help me to resolve that issue?

Comment: I edited my answer add li element instead of img in find. Find using parent will give child element also

Comment: Thank you, Kavitha. let me try this way